# Чем отличается defaultProps от state?

Tags: reactjs

Можно ли изменить значение при клике у objectTypes

```
static defaultProps = {
    objectTypes: {
      'polygon': Path
      'rectangle': Rect,
      'circle': Circle
    },
    snapToGrid: 1,
    svgStyle: {},
    insertMenu: InsertMenu
  };
```

или только у state можно менять состояния?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется менять `defaultProps` в зависимости от действий юзера - нельзя.
[defaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) - это всего лишь `props` по умолчанию на случай если при создании экземпляра компонента их не указали.
То что меняется - это `state` на том или ином уровне, главное разберитесь - на каком.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться